# Error: spawn EPERM at ChildProcess.spawn at Object.spawn at module.exports. at runOnAllDevices yarn run android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: 1]Have any idea what's happening, when I am trying to run my project on android using yarn run android

"react-native": "0.66.4",
"yarn" : v1.22.19

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps :

```
cd android

xattr -l ./gradlew
```

If you see com.apple.quarantine in there, you can remove it by running

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ./gradlew
```

The only other thing you may want to check is that your script is executable:

```
ls -l ./gradlew
```

There should be some x‘s in there (read `man chmod` for more details).

If it’s not, you can add the executable flag to it:

```
chmod +x android

chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Delete `.gradle` folder inside `android` directory.
try to run `npx react-native run-android`